# select id from multiple tables then join by other and index by table taha id exist

Tags: php, mysql

I have this tables in mysql:
Table user for all user signing up in website,
Table profile, and Table groups that list groups tables.

My user can sign up and submit in groups such as childhood... .

I want to select userid from groups tables (profile_childhood, profile_classmate,..) and there username from user and name from profile
and specify what groups they are submitted!

and result in php (BY mysql):

"d yar" is submitted in classmate and childhood and martial groups

"rayan" is submitted in childhood group

"bob" is submitted in classmate and childhood groups

in mysql:

```
mysql> select id, username from user;
+-----+----------------+
| id  | username       |
+-----+----------------+
|  96 | didar          |
|  97 | amirecoy       |
|  98 | rayan          |
| 122 | aaaa           |
| 123 | bbbb           |
| 124 | cccc           |
+-----+----------------+

mysql> select userid, name from profile;
+--------+-----------+
| userid | name      |
+--------+-----------+
|     96 | d yar     |
|     97 | amir      |
|     98 | rayan     |
|    122 | alex      |
|    123 | bob       |
|    124 | captain   |
+--------+-----------+

mysql> select t_name, name from groups;
+-------------------+----------------+
| t_name            | name           |
+-------------------+----------------+
| profile_classmate | classmate      |
| profile_martial   | martial_status |
| profile_retiree   | retiree        |
| profile_childhood | childhood      |
+-------------------+----------------+

mysql> select userid from profile_classmate;
+--------+
| userid |
+--------+
|     96 |
|    123 |
+--------+

mysql> select userid from profile_childhood;
+--------+
| userid |
+--------+
|     96 |
|     98 |
|    122 |
|    123 |
|    124 |
+--------+

mysql> select userid from profile_martial;
+--------+
| userid |
+--------+
|     96 |
+--------+
```

Comment: SELECT a.userid AS classmate, b.userid AS martial, c.userid AS tiree, d.userid AS childhood, u.username FROM profile_classmate AS a, profile_martial AS b, profile_retiree AS c, profile_childhood AS d LEFT JOIN user AS u ON userid = u.id WHERE u.role_id = 5 AND u.id != 96